# How to count the number of unique characters in a file?

Tags: python, ruby, perl, bash

Given a file in UTF-8, containing characters in various languages, how can I obtain a count of the number of unique characters it contains, while excluding a select number of symbols (e.g.: "!", "@", "#", ".") from this count?

Comment: You can not do it with only bash. You need to write a full program in bash. In that case its better to use a programming language.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you must use "bash"?

Comment: @fbernardo: Would be some strange homework, that :)

Comment: It would be a lot more interesting if there was a timing test involved.

Comment: Is a file in UTF-8 the same as a file/text in Unicode, in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a Perl one-liner:

```
echo -e "aba\ncfg!ഡ.#g" | perl -C7 -ne 'for(split(//)){if ($_ !~ /[!@#.]/) { print $_."\n"}}' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

**OUTPUT** `7`

If you want to ignore newline:

```
echo -e "aba\ncfg!ഡ.#g" | perl -C7 -ne 'for(split(//)){if ($_ !~ /[!@#.\n]/) { print $_."\n"}}' | sort | uniq | wc -l
```

**OUTPUT** `6`

Comment: One liner in perl+bash you mean?

Comment: @gnibbler I said **using** a one-liner. You're right, that was a misphrase - wrote one thing meant another. Corrected it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The first bash/perl 1-liner makes error "bash: !ഡ.#g: event not found"

Answer (score 8):

Here’s a bash solution. :)

```
bash$ perl -CSD -ne 'BEGIN { $s{$_}++ for split //, q(!@#.) }
                     $s{$_}++ || $c++ for split //;
                     END { print "$c\n" }' *.utf8
```

Comment: "Here's a bash solution" ... NOT! ;)

Comment: tchrist, what would be the in-script equivalent of `-CSD`?

Comment: @JoelBerger The in-script equivalent of `-CSD` is `use open qw(:std :utf8)`.

Answer (score 5):

In Python:

```
import itertools, codecs

predicate = set('!@#.').__contains__
unique_char_count = len(set(itertools.ifilterfalse(
                      predicate, itertools.chain.from_iterable(codecs.open(filename, encoding="UTF-8")))))
```

When you iterate over a file, you get lines. `chain` joins them together, so iterating over it you get characters. `ifilterfalse` eliminates the characters that meet the condition, with the condition defined as membership in a set of the disallowed characters.

Without itertools:

```
import codecs
disallowed = set('!@#.')
unique_char_count = len(set(char for line in codecs.open(filename, encoding="UTF-8") for char in line 
                              if char not in disallowed))
```

Using set operations:

```
import codecs
unique = set()
any(unique.update(line) for line in codecs.open(filename, encoding="UTF-8"))
unique.difference_update('!@#.')
unique_char_count = len(unique)
```

Comment: I think you need a * or a .from_iterable for chain to work that way.

Comment: @DSM Thanks, missed the `.from_iterable`. Also added the non-itertools version.

Comment: You might want to specify the encoding with that `open` call.

Comment: @NiklasB. Right, there are supposed to be for UTF-8 files.

Comment: @NiklasB. @tchrist I've used `codecs.open` and specified UTF-8.

Comment: +1. I think the 3rd one is the way to go. Simple and probably the best performance

Comment: When I tried these, why do I get this error: `NameError: name 'filename' is not defined`?

Comment: @Village That's a variable where you store the filename (obviously). Either define it in the file, or if you're using the file from the command line you probably want something like `filename = sys.argv[1]`.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby, using sets:

```
require 'set'
string = 'ababbbababbabcdcccdbbaaba'
ignore = 'c'
(Set.new(string.chars) - Set.new(ignore.chars)).count
# => 3
```

- `string` is an input string
- `ignore` is a string with characters to ignore
- `string.chars` is a list of chars in a string
- `Set.new` makes a set out of it
- `-` gives the difference between two sets
- `count` is the number of elements in the resulting set

Comment: `ignore.chars` is enough; it doesn't need to be converted to a set.

Answer (score 3):

Another ruby one:

```
#encoding: utf-8
string = '@étude#@étude ฒณ!'
ignore = '!@#.'
p string.chars.to_a.uniq.join.delete(ignore).size #=>8
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll just throw in my no-language-required option for good measure:

```
sed 's/[!@#.]//g' /path/to/file | sed 's/./\0\n/g' | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: That doesn’t even come *anywhere **close*** to working on my system for UTF-8 files. Before the `wc`, there are a bunch of lines like `0n0n0n0n`, `0n0n0n0n0n0n0n0n`, etc. And yes, LANG=`en_US.UTF-8`. You aren’t using POSIX-standard `sed`, are you?

Comment: @Andrew Kandels - I think it's a great solution.  If the original file is 16-bit Unicode, you can always use iconv: `iconv -f utf-16 -t ascii sourcefile | sed 's/[!@#.]//g' /path/to/file | sed 's/./\0\n/g' | sort -u | wc -l`

Comment: Sorry, spaced on the UTF-8 part. @paulsm4's addition should fix that problem though.

Comment: @AndrewKandels I don’t think so. You cannot convert to ASCII without losing all the Unicode. Furthermore, it is not portable to try to tell `sed` to use `\0` to mean the whole pattern nor even `\n` to mean a literal newline, because those are not part of the POSIX standard. There’s also the Unicode issue still. **So much for not needing a language! :(** On the other hand, replacing those with something like  `perl -CS -pe 's/(.)/$1\n/g'` ***is portable***, because there are not all these myriad mutually incompatible versions of `perl` the way there are of `sed`.

Comment: I didn't need it for UTF-8 + google took me here + this is the best solution for me = upvote (but I used `tr -d` for the first part :) )

Answer (score 2):

I did this in python after 3 hours of research , but i did it

```
fname = "temp.txt"
num_lines = 0
num_words = 0
num_chars = 0
num_uniq  = 0
a = []
exclude = ",.@#$"
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        words = line.split()
        for word in words:
                char = list(word)
                a = a + char
        num_lines += 1
        num_words += len(words)
        num_chars += len(line)
print "Lines:%s\nWords:%s\nChars:%s" % (num_lines, num_words, num_chars)
num_uniq =  len(set(a)-set(exclude))
print "Unique Characters:%d" % (num_uniq)
```

here is the output

```
Lines:6
Words:74
Chars:385
Unique Characters:26
```

Answer (score 1):

Use sets in python.
lets say you want to find out unique characters in file url.txt

```
f=open('url.txt')
a=''
for x in f:
    x=x.split(' ')
    for y in x:
     a+=y
unique=set(a)-set('@!#.')  #add the characters that you wanna neglect in the second set
print(unique)
print('unique characters : ',len(unique))
```

lets say url.txt contains :

```
Google --!  google.com  --!  coolest search engine 

facebook --!  facebook.com  --!  biggest social network 

yahoo --!  yahoo.com  --!  biggest web portal
```

output will be:

```
{'a', 'G', 'm', '\n', 'n', 'c', 'b', 'e', 'g', 'f', 'i', 'h', 'k', '-', 'l', 'o', 'p', 's', 'r', 't', 'w', 'y'}
unique characters :  22
```

Comment: My answer already gives several Python versions that are essentially the same. Also, the performance of your string builder is __terrible__. Adding strings is slow -- if you have to strip spaces and join the lines, you should use something like `''.join(''.join(x.split()) for x in f)` which will be much faster. See my answer for ways to do it without building a long string.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative:

```
filename='/somewhere/my-file-in-utf8'

iconv -f UTF8 -t UTF16 $filename | tail -c +3 |  \
perl -pi -e "s/\x00\@//g; s/\x00\!//g; s/\x00\#//g; s/\x00\.//g;" | \
od | cut -b 8- | xargs -n 1 | sort | uniq | wc -l
```